# HtmlAgilityPack NodeCollection

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am trying to get a collection of nodes from the yahoo nfl sports page....

> string path = "http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/scoreboard";

```
       HtmlWeb page = new HtmlWeb();
       var score_page = page.Load(path);

       HtmlNodeCollection scores = score_page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@tr class='game']/td");
```

this code returns null ....not sure why!

can someone help with this?

Thank You

Comment: Looking at the source code, the class isn't "Game" but "game link"

Comment: yes, it seems the name of the class has changed since I posted. I use Google Chrome "inspect element" to find the xpath. I changed the code to "game  link" and it is working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack looks at the full attribute contents and doesn't parse it to split the Class into "Game" and "Link", instead it just sees "game link". If you want to check for a class containing "game", use the `contains()` function of xpath instead, or use an extension to the HTML Agility Path that allows you to do CSS selectors, such as [Fizzler (archive)](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/).

#### 3rd party update 2021

To support a css selector a [third party library](https://html-agility-pack.net/third-party-library#htmlagilitypackcssselectors) is still needed. Currently [html-agility-pack.net](https://html-agility-pack.net) links to these libraries

- [Fizzler](https://github.com/atifaziz/Fizzler)
- [HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors](https://html-agility-pack.net/third-party-library#htmlagilitypackcssselectors) with two options [one for .Net Core](https://github.com/trenoncourt/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore)